# unable to convert date from character string

Tags: c#, sql

I am fetching quarterly records from sql server. The records are like total debits and credits in each quarter of year. In my sql query I have made the quarters and the year is dynamic as you can see in the code.

```
public List<QuarterlyExpenseList> GetExpenseDataQuarterly(string Id, string Year)
        {
            string SQL = "select aspnetusers.username, SUM(case when Expense.Type='credit' and (Expense.Date>='@year-01-01' and Expense.Date<='@year-03-31') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterOneCredits,";
            SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='credit' and (Expense.Date>='@year-04-01' and Expense.Date<='@year-06-30') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterTwoCredits,";
            SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='credit' and (Expense.Date>='@year-07-01' and Expense.Date<='@year-09-30') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterThreeCredits,";
            SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='credit' and (Expense.Date>='@year-10-01' and Expense.Date<='@year-12-31') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterFourCredits,";
            SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='debit' and (Expense.Date>='@year-01-01' and Expense.Date<='@year-03-31') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterOneDebits,";
            SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='debit' and (Expense.Date>='@year-04-01' and Expense.Date<='@year-06-30') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterTwoDebits,";
            SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='debit' and (Expense.Date>='@year-07-01' and Expense.Date<='@year-09-30') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterThreeDebits,";
            SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='debit' and (Expense.Date>='@year-10-01' and Expense.Date<='@year-12-31') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterFourDebits";
            SQL += " from Expense inner join AspNetUsers on AspNetUsers.Id=Expense.MadeBy";
            if (Id == null)
            {
                SQL += " group by aspnetusers.username";
            }
            else
            {
                SQL += " where Expense.MadeBy=@id group by AspNetUsers.UserName group by aspnetusers.username";
            }

            using (IDbConnection cn=Connection)
            {
                cn.Open();
                List<QuarterlyExpenseList> objList = cn.Query<QuarterlyExpenseList>(SQL, new { year = Year, id = Id }).ToList();
                return objList;
            }
        }
```

here I am getting an exception of `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` Can somebody tell me what does it mean and how can I get rid of it

Comment: Why don't you add the variables when creating the SQL query ? like `SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='credit' and (Expense.Date>='"+ Year + "-04-01' and Expense.Date<='"+ Year + "-06-30') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterTwoCredits,";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed the dynamic year "@year" outside character string as it is a dynamic value. When written like '@year-04-01' SQL was treating "@year" as a character string and not as a dynamic value.

Use the following code:

```
public List<QuarterlyExpenseList> GetExpenseDataQuarterly(string Id, string Year)
            {
                string SQL = "select aspnetusers.username, SUM(case when Expense.Type='credit' and (Expense.Date>=@year+'-01-01' and Expense.Date<=@year+'-03-31') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterOneCredits,";
                SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='credit' and (Expense.Date>=@year+'-04-01' and Expense.Date<=@year+'-06-30') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterTwoCredits,";
                SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='credit' and (Expense.Date>=@year+'-07-01' and Expense.Date<=@year+'-09-30') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterThreeCredits,";
                SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='credit' and (Expense.Date>=@year+'-10-01' and Expense.Date<=@year+'-12-31') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterFourCredits,";
                SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='debit' and (Expense.Date>=@year+'-01-01' and Expense.Date<=@year+'-03-31') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterOneDebits,";
                SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='debit' and (Expense.Date>=@year+'-04-01' and Expense.Date<=@year+'-06-30') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterTwoDebits,";
                SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='debit' and (Expense.Date>=@year+'-07-01' and Expense.Date<=@year+'-09-30') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterThreeDebits,";
                SQL += " SUM(case when Expense.Type='debit' and (Expense.Date>=@year+'-10-01' and Expense.Date<=@year+'-12-31') then Expense.Amount else 0 end) as QuarterFourDebits";
                SQL += " from Expense inner join AspNetUsers on AspNetUsers.Id=Expense.MadeBy";
                if (Id == null)
                {
                    SQL += " group by aspnetusers.username";
                }
                else
                {
                    SQL += " where Expense.MadeBy=@id group by AspNetUsers.UserName group by aspnetusers.username";
                }

                using (IDbConnection cn=Connection)
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    List<QuarterlyExpenseList> objList = cn.Query<QuarterlyExpenseList>(SQL, new { year = Year, id = Id }).ToList();
                    return objList;
                }
            }
```

Comment: @CodeCaster I removed the dynamic year "@year" outside character string as it is a dynamic value. When written like '@year-04-01' SQL was treating "@year" as a character string and not as a dynamic value.